# Oracle changing timestamp column value for Daylight Savings

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a timestamp column which has value 12/02/2019 02:00:00. But when the months of daylight savings come the value automatically changes to 12/02/2019 01:00:00.Now if I make the timezone to Europe/Istanbul it becomes the original value. But I have to keep changing the timezone every few months when daylight savings happens.I need the query to return the original value. Again for normal months I have to set the timezone to Asia/Istanbul otherwise the value changes forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column is defined with the [timestamp with local time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E7CA339A-2093-4FE4-A36E-1D09593591D3) data type, it will be stored with the *database* time zone and displayed with the *session* timezone.

See how the *displayed* value (not the *stored* value) for column C3 changes in this example from 20:28 to 21:28:

```
SQL> create table t (
   c1 timestamp,
   c2 timestamp with time zone,
   c3 timestamp with local time zone
);

SQL> alter session set time_zone = 'Europe/Rome';

SQL> insert into t (c1, c2, c3) values (systimestamp, systimestamp, systimestamp);

SQL> select * from t;

C1                                                 C2                                  C3                                 
-------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------- -----------------------------------
20/08/2020 20:28:17.942586                         20/08/2020 20:28:17.942586 +02:00   20/08/2020 20:28:17.942586

SQL> alter session set time_zone = 'Europe/Istanbul';

SQL> select * from t;

C1                                                 C2                                  C3                                 
-------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------- -----------------------------------
20/08/2020 20:28:17.942586                         20/08/2020 20:28:17.942586 +02:00   20/08/2020 21:28:17.942586
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE "TIMESTAMP_TABLE_TURKEY" (    "AUQ_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, "AUD_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, "AUS_ID" NUMBER(10,0), "TSK_ID" NUMBER(10,0),"AUQ_SCHEDULED_DTTM" TIMESTAMP (6),  "AUQ_CREATED_DTTM" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE, "AUQ_DESC" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, "AUQ_LOOKBACK_FREQ_CMP_ID" NUMBER(10,0), "AUQ_LOOKBACK_PIVOT_DTTM" TIMESTAMP (6), "AUQ_LOOKBACK_START_DTTM" TIMESTAMP (6),  );
   
This is the table creation query. I haven't set the timestamp column with local time zone.